# NSManagedObjectContext and GCD

Tags: iphone, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

From Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1):

> You should give each thread its own
>   entirely private managed object
>   context and keep their associated
>   object graphs separated on a
>   per-thread basis.

How does that scale to Grand Central Dispatch, where you have absolutely no control over threads, which are created automagically on your behalf?

The way I do it now is to have one `NSManagedObjectContext` for each dispatch queue, but that's the thing: a dispatch queue doesn't necessarily use the same thread every time, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Apple mean when they say that a NSManagedObjectContext is owned by the thread or queue that created it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800889/what-does-apple-mean-when-they-say-that-a-nsmanagedobjectcontext-is-owned-by-the)

Comment: As Nick points out, the other question has a few pretty good explanations for this (particularly Ben's).  Also, without breaking NDA, you may wish to read about what's changed in Lion for Core Data (which I assume will find its way to iOS 5.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ["What does Apple mean when they say that a NSManagedObjectContext is owned by the thread or queue that created it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800889/what-does-apple-mean-when-they-say-that-a-nsmanagedobjectcontext-is-owned-by-the) on SO will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked at this article, but maybe you are interested in this post  [Passing around a NSManagedObjectContext on the iPhone](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/01/07/passing-around-a-nsmanagedobjectcontext-on-the-iphone/) by Marcus Zara.