# How to implement Thread Confinement to Support Concurrency?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, concurrency

I'm reading the Core Data Programming Guide and under the ["Use Thread Confinement to Support Concurrency"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW2) section it mentions a recommended pattern:

> Create a separate managed object context for each thread and share a single persistent store coordinator.

Can somebody point me to an example implementation of such a pattern?

I am particularly interested in implementations that handle blocks.  We frequently put things in a block and add it to a queue...and sometimes those objects contain references to the main thread's MOC.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800889/what-does-apple-mean-when-they-say-that-a-nsmanagedobjectcontext-is-owned-by-the for a discussion of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a old question but I found  a really good tutorial for this aproach:
http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/2/the-concurrent-core-data-stack
http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/

I hope this help some one with the same question. :).

Comment: yes...this is an old question...  :)  The links are handy tho and are in line with what I've learned since I asked this question.